# best practices for recoding ID strings into other strings

Tags: r

I have a column with a series of ID's that I need to recode into something that's a bit more intuitive. This is an example of my file:

```
ID = c("DR-0001", "DR-0002", "DR-0003", "DR-0004", "DR-0001", "DR-0002", "DR-0001")
df <- data.frame(ID)
```

where I want to create a new column where I relabel entries. In pseudo code I want the following:

```
df$ID_useful = 2019/01 if df$ID == "DR-0001", 2015/06 if df$ID == "DR-0002" etc.
```

so that the end result would be something like this:

```
ID = c("DR-0001", "DR-0002", "DR-0003", "DR-0004", "DR-0001", "DR-0002", "DR-0001")
ID_useful = c("2019/01", "2015/06", "1995/02", "2012/08", "2019/01", "2015/06", "2019/01")
```

And I'm not sure how to do this without creating a billion ifelse command lines. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we make those unique key/value dataset, then it is more efficient with a join

```
library(dplyr)
keydat <- data.frame(ID = sprintf('DR-%04d', 1:4),
      ID_useful = c("2019/01", "2015/06", "1995/02", "2012/08"))
df %>%
    left_join(keydat)
```

-output

```
joining, by = "ID"
       ID ID_useful
1 DR-0001   2019/01
2 DR-0002   2015/06
3 DR-0003   1995/02
4 DR-0004   2012/08
5 DR-0001   2019/01
6 DR-0002   2015/06
7 DR-0001   2019/01
```

Comment: Here's a wrinkle - the ID's aren't actually sequential, that's just the spaceholder I put in for the post

Comment: @tchoup My example was just to show you construct a keydat dataset.  If it is not sequential, you may have to construct that by each value

Comment: @tchoup i.e. if there are no patterns, you have to construct the keydat as `keydat <- data.frame(ID = c("DR-0001", "DR-0005", ...` and the corresponding values in `ID_useful`

Answer (score 1):

Another option with base R using `setNames`

```
dic <- sprintf("DR-%04d", 1:4)
dic_useful <- c("2019/01", "2015/06", "1995/02", "2012/08")
transform(
    df,
    ID_useful = setNames(dic_useful, dic)[ID]
)
```

gives

```
       ID ID_useful
1 DR-0001   2019/01
2 DR-0002   2015/06
3 DR-0003   1995/02
4 DR-0004   2012/08
5 DR-0001   2019/01
6 DR-0002   2015/06
7 DR-0001   2019/01
```